# Task scheduling in laravel forge

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I've hosted my app in Digital Ocean with Laravel Forge and have created a artisan command to run through schedule [Nightly].

The artisan command runs smoothly via terminal but returns **No such file or directory** while running it through `Scheduled Jobs`manually from Laravel Forge.

The command for the job is:

`php /home/forge/sitename.com/artisan Instagram:fetch`

The artisan command `php /home/forge/sitename.com/artisan Inspire`  **i.e php artisan inspire**  returns the correct output.

While the above mentioned custom artisan returns **No such file or directory**

**app\Console\Commands\FetchInstagram.php**'s handel method:

```
    public function handle()
{
    $instagram = new Instagram('api-key');
    $posts = $instagram->media(); //gets 20 latest insta posts of a user
    // dd($posts);
    $fromDBs = Insta::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(20)->get(); //get last 20 rows from table
    foreach( $posts as $post)
    {
        Insta::firstOrCreate([
            'thumb_link' => $post->images->thumbnail->url  ,
            'standard_link' => $post->images->standard_resolution->url  ,
            'caption' => $post->caption->text
        ]);
    }
}
```

Code from `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\FetchInstagram'
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('Instagram:fetch')
    ->daily();
}
```

Comment: Can we see the job?

Comment: You are probably missing some `folders` or additional structure that didn't come along with the application, check where you are storing stuff from that command or accessing some folders

Comment: @Tanja same issue here, used to work before though. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: @Wonka The issue is fixed. I tried it next day with same settings and it worked.